# How to map array from localStorage to table in reactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactstrap

I am trying to map array data from localStorage to my react table but the formatting appears like this:
[image]

But I would like it to be formatted like this:

[image]

The current code I am using is this:

```
const get = JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem('pls'));
const setUs = ([get]);
...
function handleSubmit(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var js = localStorage.getItem('Data');
   var loc = [js];
   loc.push(document.getElementById("inputKey").value);
   localStorage.setItem("Data", loc);
}
...
return(
   <div>
     <Table>
       <tbody>
         {(setUs.map((m,i) => (
             <tr key={`${m+i}`}>
                <td>{m}</td>
             </tr>
          )))}
       <tbody>
     </Table>
   </div>
)
...
```

I am not sure how to format it like the second image. I have tried using spread operators, tring different methods such as `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify()` but the array turns into something like `[[[,\\input1\]\\input2\\]\input3\\]`. Any help would be appreciated.

I am using reactJS and reactstrap.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hooks` for `localStorage`

```js
const useLocalStorage = (name, defaultValue) => {

    const [currentValue, setCurrentValue] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(name)) ?? defaultValue);
    const callback = useDelay(delay, currentValue);

    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem(name, JSON.stringify(currentValue));
    }, [currentValue]);

    return [currentValue, setCurrentValue];
}

export default useLocalStorage;
```

How to use it?

```js
import useLocalStorage from '...';

const Component = () => {
    const [pls, setPls] = useLocalStorage('pls', []);

    return (
        <>
            {pls.map(v => (
                H E R E
            ))}
        </>
    );
};
```